# Replacing PatternAnalyzer class deprecated in org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.PatternAnalyzer

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

What can I use to replace the deprecated class PatternAnalyzer?
org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.PatternAnalyzer

source: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/analyzers-common/index-all.html

We are trying to upgrade from elasticsearch 5.6 to es version 7.9

This is the gradle dependency

```
compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.9.0'
compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.9.0'
```

Then this the Tokenizer.java class

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet;
import org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.PatternAnalyzer;

    
         private static Iterable<String> splitString(String str) {
                PatternAnalyzer analyzer = new PatternAnalyzer(
                        Pattern.compile("(\\s+|-+)"), true, new CharArraySet(10, false));
        
                List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
                String[] initialTokens = str.split("\\s+");
                for (String token : initialTokens) {
                    if (token.matches("\\d+\\w*\\-\\d+\\w*")) {
                        results.add(token);
                    } else {
                        try {
                            TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream(token, token);
                            tokenStream.reset();
                            CharTermAttribute termAttribute = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        
                            while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
                                results.add(termAttribute.toString());
                            }
        
                            tokenStream.end();
                            tokenStream.close();
        
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
        
                analyzer.close();
                return results;
            }
```

Build Error:

```
Tokenizer.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet;
                                      ^
  symbol:   class CharArraySet
  location: package org.apache.lucene.analysis.util

Tokenizer.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
import org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.PatternAnalyzer;
                                       ^
  symbol:   class PatternAnalyzer
  location: package org.elasticsearch.index.analysis

Tokenizer.java:157: error: cannot find symbol
        PatternAnalyzer analyzer = new PatternAnalyzer(
        ^
  symbol:   class PatternAnalyzer
  location: class Tokenizer

Tokenizer.java:157: error: cannot find symbol
        PatternAnalyzer analyzer = new PatternAnalyzer(
                                       ^
  symbol:   class PatternAnalyzer
  location: class Tokenizer

Tokenizer.java:158: error: cannot find symbol
                Pattern.compile("(\\s+|-+)"), true, new CharArraySet(10, false));
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class CharArraySet
  location: class Tokenizer
```

Then I tried to replace with PattenTokenizer and getting this new build error

https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/package-summary.html#package.description

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.CharArraySet;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.pattern.PatternTokenizer;

private static Iterable<String> splitString(String str) {
        PatternTokenizer analyzer = new PatternTokenizer(
                Pattern.compile("(\\s+|-+)"), true, new CharArraySet(10, false));

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] initialTokens = str.split("\\s+");
        for (String token : initialTokens) {
            if (token.matches("\\d+\\w*\\-\\d+\\w*")) {
                results.add(token);
            } else {
                try {
                    TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream(token, token);
                    tokenStream.reset();
                    CharTermAttribute termAttribute = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

                    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
                        results.add(termAttribute.toString());
                    }

                    tokenStream.end();
                    tokenStream.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }

        analyzer.close();
        return results;
    }
```

New Build Error:

```
  Tokenizer.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet;
                                          ^
      symbol:   class CharArraySet
      location: package org.apache.lucene.analysis.util
    
    Tokenizer.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    import org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.PatternAnalyzer;
                                           ^
      symbol:   class PatternAnalyzer
      location: package org.elasticsearch.index.analysis
    
    Tokenizer.java:160: error: incompatible types: Pattern cannot be converted to AttributeFactory
                    Pattern.compile("(\\s+|-+)"), true, new CharArraySet(10, false));
                                   ^
    Tokenizer.java:169: error: cannot find symbol
                        TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream(token, token);
                                                          ^
      symbol:   method tokenStream(String,String)
      location: variable analyzer of type PatternTokenizer
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] to add a transcription of your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: What does "*getting issues*" mean? Do you get a compilation error? If so: please [edit] the post, add the compiler error and highlight the line of code causing the compilation error. Does it throw an exception? If so: please [edit] the post, add the stack trace and highlight the line of code causing the exception. Do you observe unexpected behaviour? If so: please [edit] the post, add a [MRE], as we as expected and observed output.